# Curl request is failing

Tags: php, curl

I have this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.infoempleo.com/");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);  
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie );  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET ,true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('HeaderName: HeaderValue'));
  //  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$homepage = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($homepage);
```

But is is not working, it is working with google.com but not with http://www.infoempleo.com/. 
What is wrong in this code?

I tried online ping utility like http://network-tools.com/ and the server is not responding to ping request, but they are responding to http headers. 
so what do I need to set in the cURL request to make it work ?

But this code works

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "blog/wordpress/wp-login.php");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

how ?

Comment: Maybe your IP's been blocked for abusive scraping? What does `curl_error($ch)` say immediately after you do the `curl_exec()`?

Comment: @Marc B I am getting fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\curl2.php on line 37 and this line is curl_exec ($ch);

Comment: Probably your server's IP has been blocked by that site, and is doing it by just ignoring packets from your server, rather than replying with a "host unreachable" or "connection refused" type error.

Comment: @Marc B I updated the code. but second code works how ?
as well as only ping is not able to ping server.

Answer (score 2):

It may restrict user agents. Try to change

```
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
```

with

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
```